# RegEx in Visual Studio to remove region and contents within

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2010 search and replace.
I would like to search for all regions in my file and remove it along with the contents

For example,

```
#region Blah

These are the contents of Blah
Line 2 of blah is even more interesting
blah blah blah blah.........

#endregion
```

I would like to remove all of the contents above.

Comment: I use VS2010 and have used thier regex engine. Have you read the help docs on its syntax? If not, its a good place to start, because makeng a regex for this could be very simple.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
\#region[\s\S]*?\#endregion.*$
```

With multiline and global modifiers. Example: http://regex101.com/r/hL0vA5

Comment: This is not working. I'm assuming visual studio search and replace regex is slightly different.

Comment: Might be, yeah -- not familiar with it's search/replace functionality at all, sorry.

Comment: It appears that the hashtag needs to be escaped. So this \#region(.|\n)*\#endregion.*$ works but unfortunately, it picks up the first #region in my file and does not stop until the last #endregion in the file. I'd like it to pick them up individually.

Comment: Use a non-greedy match then `\#region(.|\n)*?\#endregion.*$` Updated regex101 link.

Comment: What about `\#region[\s\S]*?\#endregion.*$`? I think it's cleaner and more semantically correct. :P

Comment: @tenub aye, yeah, much better.